# MvvmCross ILocationWatcher Success Action not firing - Android

Tags: geolocation, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm trying to integrate the MvxGeolocation plugin for android and I'm having issues getting the watcher to fire the success event. It just does not fire.

I've followed the documentation from `MvvmCross` (https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins#location).

As per the documentation I've created a separate Service that publishes messages to the `ViewModel`, rather than have the `IMvxLocationWatcher` hooked directly up to the `ViewModel`.

```
public class GeoLocationService: IGeoLocationService
    {
        private readonly IMvxLocationWatcher _watcher;
        private readonly IMvxMessenger _messenger;

        public GeoLocationService(IMvxLocationWatcher watcher, IMvxMessenger messenger)
        {
            _watcher = watcher;

            _messenger = messenger;

            _watcher.Start(new MvxLocationOptions(), OnLocation, OnError);
        }


        public void OnLocation(MvxGeoLocation location)
        {
            var message = new LocationMessage(this, location.Coordinates.Latitude, location.Coordinates.Longitude);

            _messenger.Publish(message);
        }

        public void OnError(MvxLocationError error)
        {
            Mvx.Error("Seen location error {0}", error.Code);
        }
    }
```

The `OnLocation(MvxGeoLocation location)` method is meant to publish a message that my ViewModel subscribes too as you can see  below:-

```
public class MainViewModel : MvxViewModel
    {

        private readonly MvxSubscriptionToken _token;
        public MainViewModel(IMvxMessenger messenger)
        {
            _token = messenger.SubscribeOnMainThread<LocationMessage>(OnLocationMessage);
        }



 private void OnLocationMessage(LocationMessage locationMessage)
    {
        Lat = locationMessage.Lat;
        Lng = locationMessage.Lng;
    }

    double _latitude;
    public double Lat
    {
        get
        {
            return _latitude;
        }
        set
        {
            _latitude = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Lat);

        }
    }


    double _longitude;
    public double Lng
    {
        get
        {
            return _longitude;
        }
        set
        {
            _longitude = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Lng);
        }
        }

        string _name;

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Name);
            }
        }
    }
```

I've added Bootstrapper classes to the android application that resolve both the Messenger and LocationWatcher plugins. Ive also registered the GeoLocationService in the App class in my core library like this :-

```
public class App : MvxApplication
    {
        public App()
        {
            Mvx.ConstructAndRegisterSingleton<IGeoLocationService, GeoLocationService>();

            Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IMvxAppStart>(new MvxAppStart<MainViewModel>());
        }
    }
```

I've also edited the AndroidManifest.Xml and added the following user permissions :-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Im debugging this against a plugged in Device (Samsung S6 Edge).

Ive tested my view.xaml to ensure that binding is working by passing it some default values.. and everything is as expected.

The issue is that The Action in the Watcher class for Success or Error are never called.

Comment: Did you try other LocationOptions?

Comment: Embarrassed to have to admit this. But the code works fine, when I'm not in this underground bunker of an office. I deployed this solution to my phone and it is working everywhere else but here in my office there is no signal. I do have wifi connection however.. i assumed it would use this?

Comment: Only if you use the Fused provider. The default one only uses GPS.

Comment: COuld you point out how i add the capability for wifi? just pointme at an article? if possible?

Comment: Just add the MvvmCross.Plugins.Location.Fused package and use that instead.

Comment: Thanks, doesnt allow me to install it into my PCL? Profile 111, Profile 7, Profile 49. tried removing Windows 8.1, Im targeting .Net 4.5

Comment: It is for Droid only, the PCL will still just have the regular Location plugin